# iterate column in row in table by JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, each

I have a trouble with `each()` in JQuery. I have a table contain information about student include: **name**, **math score**, **physical score**, **chemistry score** and last column is **average score** has default value is "?".

I want when I click to button account average, column average score will display **average = (math + physical + chemistry)/3**. Currently, I leave the class of the 3 score columns as `score` and iterate like this:

```
   $("#btn-average").click(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".score").each(function(value) {
      value = parseFloat($(this).text());
      sum += value;
    });
    var average = sum / 3;
    $(".average-score").text(average.toFixed(1));
  });
```

However, if when I add a new student to the table, all the points will be added when the average is calculated, I don't know what to do. Please, help me, thank you so much.
This is my table

```
<table id="my-table" class="student-score">
      <tr>
        <th class="table-name-column"></th>
        <th class="table-name-column">name</th>
        <th class="table-name-column">math score</th>
        <th class="table-name-column">physical score</th>
        <th class="table-name-column">chemistry score</th>
        <th class="table-name-column">average score</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="student-info">
        <td class="table-content">1</td>
        <td class="table-content">Peter</td>
        <td id="math-score" class="table-content score">9</td>
        <td id="physical-score" class="table-content score">8.5</td>
        <td id="chemistry-score" class="table-content score">7.5</td>
        <td id="average-score" class="table-content average-score">?</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that you itterate over all ".score" fields in one go, you need to break that up into induvidual chunks.

The most common way would be to itterate the rows, and inside that itterate the ".score" fields.

Here is an example:

```js
$("#btn-average").click(function() {
  $(".student-info").each(function() {
    let sum = 0;
    let count = 0;
    $(this).find(".score").each(function() {
      value = parseFloat($(this).text());
      sum += value;
      count++;
    });
    const average = sum / count;
    $(this).find(".average-score").text(average.toFixed(1));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table" class="student-score">
  <tr>
    <th class="table-name-column"></th>
    <th class="table-name-column">name</th>
    <th class="table-name-column">math score</th>
    <th class="table-name-column">physical score</th>
    <th class="table-name-column">chemistry score</th>
    <th class="table-name-column">average score</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="student-info">
    <td class="table-content">1</td>
    <td class="table-content">Peter</td>
    <td id="math-score" class="table-content score">9</td>
    <td id="physical-score" class="table-content score">8.5</td>
    <td id="chemistry-score" class="table-content score">7.5</td>
    <td id="average-score" class="table-content average-score">?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="student-info">
    <td class="table-content">2</td>
    <td class="table-content">Max</td>
    <td id="math-score" class="table-content score">3</td>
    <td id="physical-score" class="table-content score">5.5</td>
    <td id="chemistry-score" class="table-content score">9.5</td>
    <td id="average-score" class="table-content average-score">?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btn-average">calc sum</button>
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I've been stuck with this problem for almost 1 week. Your way solves it even if I have an extra column of points.

Answer (score 0):

First You must use `each` for row with `student-info` class and calculate sum of its `score` class elements values then calculate average for this row and continue this procedure for other row with `student-info` class

```js
$("#btn-average").click(function() {

    $(".student-info").each(function(){
        var sum = 0;
        $(this).find(".score").each(function(value) {
            value = parseFloat($(this).text());
            sum += value;
        });
        var average = sum / 3;
        $(this).find(".average-score").text(average.toFixed(1));
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table" class="student-score">
      <tr>
        <th class="table-name-column"></th>
        <th class="table-name-column">name</th>
        <th class="table-name-column">math score</th>
        <th class="table-name-column">physical score</th>
        <th class="table-name-column">chemistry score</th>
        <th class="table-name-column">average score</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="student-info">
        <td class="table-content">1</td>
        <td class="table-content">Peter</td>
        <td id="math-score" class="table-content score">9</td>
        <td id="physical-score" class="table-content score">8.5</td>
        <td id="chemistry-score" class="table-content score">7.5</td>
        <td id="average-score" class="table-content average-score">?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="student-info">
        <td class="table-content">1</td>
        <td class="table-content">Peter</td>
        <td id="math-score" class="table-content score">8</td>
        <td id="physical-score" class="table-content score">9.5</td>
        <td id="chemistry-score" class="table-content score">6.5</td>
        <td id="average-score" class="table-content average-score">?</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="btn-average" value="AVG" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really solved my problem